# Where is the MySQL configuration file (my.cnf) located in a scalable application on OpenShift Online?

Tags: mysql, openshift

I have a scalable app on Openshift Online and I need to make few edits to my.cnf.
Where is this file is located? If in child gear, how do I connect to it?

Comment: there's this URL you may connect to in order to configure the server. The URL is stored in the [`OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_URL` environment variable](https://developers.openshift.com/en/databases-mysql.html) (you probably noticed it though).

Answer (score 2):

At least two ways to get the login@host of your mysql gear:

```
rhc app-show --gears ssh -n <yourdomain> -a <yourapp>
```

*If you have one domain, skip the `-n <yourdomain>`, and if you run it from the git folder of your app, skip the `-a <yourapp>` too.*

Or using [broker REST API](http://docs.openshift.org/origin-m4/rest_api/rest-api-1-6.html#gear_group) and curl (or just web browser):

```
curl -X GET -u user@domain:password https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/application/536074f0194e4cdfd100000c/gear_groups
```

(replace `536074f0194e4cdfd100000c` with your application ID, you can find it with: `env | grep APP` in the `ssh` console on your app gear)

Comment: Thanks for reply. First solution didnt help much. It just tells that Mysql is running (cartridge-status? not cartridge-details may be). Second comment solved the prob. And thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way:

Take OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST: 536074f0194e4cdfd100000c-test.rhcloud.com

to SSH to database server use 
536074f0194e4cdfd100000c@536074f0194e4cdfd100000c-test.rhcloud.com

Thanks didierc.